# In the new 52 how is it possible Bruce Wayne has a 10 year old son with Talia?

Tags: dc, the-new-52

Talia's attraction to Bruce Wayne traditionally has been his impressive resume as Batman. However in the new 52 Batman is only supposed to have been operating for five years.

So how is it that Bruce Wayne had a son (Damian Wayne) with Talia Al Ghul before he started operating as Batman?

Comment: Has a new backstory been given to Talia and Bruce as of the reboot? I don't think we've seen Talia or Raz AlGul yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same video that Brett White gave for my question: [How old is Bruce Wayne at the start of the New 52?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9362/how-old-is-bruce-wayne-at-the-start-of-the-new-52) also answers this question.

> According to this video interview conducted by iFanboy with current Batman writer Scott Snyder, he is between 31-35 in Batman, which takes place in the modern day New 52 Universe.

From the video:

The writers aren't too concerned with the timeline. Because Batman could potentially be as old as 35 he could have been with Talia when he first started operating as Batman (circa Year One) at the age of 25.

While he has only been publicly visible as Batman for 5 years or so, he has been operating as Batman since he was 25. So somewhere between 6-10 years.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Bruce has been training for most of his life.  During this training, he's studied under numerous masters of multiple forms of combat.

Talia has traditionally studied almost as many forms of combat.

Perhaps they trained together at some point?

Comment: Looks like they did more than train together.