# How old is Bruce Wayne at the start of the New 52?

Tags: dc, the-new-52, batman

You might otherwise say "What is the youngest possible age Bruce Wayne could be considering all he had to accomplish up until the start of the New 52?"

Comment: If the new 52's aren't disregarding the events of and subsequently following Final Crisis, I'd have to say he's been around since the Dawn of time apparently lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this video interview](http://ifanboy.com/articles/video-scott-snyder-answers-your-questions/) conducted by iFanboy with current *Batman* writer Scott Snyder, he is **between 31-35** in *Batman*, which takes place in the modern day New 52 Universe.

*(I actually got this answer from [a comment](http://robot6.comicbookresources.com/2011/09/how-old-is-batman-and-other-questions-answered-by-scott-snyder/#comment-70664), because I did not have time to watch the entire video and I could not find a transcript online)*